# how can i modify my code so that the user can input the same colour four times but not anything outside my list range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#Colours

colourRange = ["red", "green", "blue","yellow", "magenta","cyan"]
print("Please enter colours from: ", colourRange)
colour1 = input("Please press Enter after you have entered your colour\n\
Enter your 1st colour?: ")
colour2 = input("Enter 2nd colour?: ")
colour3 = input("Enter 3rd colour?: ")
colour4 = input("Enter 4th colour?: ")
colour = [colour1,colour2,colour3,colour4]

#loop for four colour choice within list     

for i in range(4):
    while colour[i] not in colourRange:
        print(colour[i], "is not a valid colour, please \
            select another from :  ", colourRange)
        colour[i] = (input("Replace with: "))
    else:
        colourRange.remove(colour[i])
```

Comment: yes i want to validate within that list of colours but also have the option to use the same colour more than once, is that possible?

Comment: Yes.That is possible. Take the input from the user, check if its valid colour(by checking if it is in your list). If it is not valid, then tell the user, and if it is valid colour then do your business logic.

Comment: ive updated my code so that it now validates user input against my list but i now have the problem of having it ask "Enter a colour" how do i get it so that its asks enter 1st.. 2nd.. and so on instead of colour?

Comment: def getcolours():
    validColours = ["red", "green", "blue","yellow", "magenta","cyan"]
    print("Please enter colours from: ", validColours)
    print("Press enter after you have entered a colour")
    for i in range(4):  
        while True:
            colour = input("Enter a colour:")
            if colour in validColours:
                break
            print("Invalid colour chosen")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **much simpler** if you write a function to get one valid colour, then call it several times.

```
def get_colour(prompt, valid_colours):
    """Allow the user to enter a single valid colour."""
    while True:
        colour = input(prompt)
        if colour in valid_colours:
            return colour
        print("Not a valid colour.")

def get_colours(n, valid_colours):
    """Get n valid colours from the user."""
    return [get_colour("Input colour {}: ".format(i+1), valid_colours) 
            for i in range(n)]

colours = get_colours(4, {"red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "magenta", "cyan"})
```

Note that:

- `n` and `valid_colours` are parameters, to make the code more flexible and reusable;
- I have used a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to simplify the code;
- the `valid_colours` are a `set`, which makes membership testing (`colour in valid_colours`) much faster (`O(1)` vs. `O(n)` for a tuple or list); and
- I have used `str.format` rather than concatenation `+`.

In use:

```
>>> colours = get_colours(4, {"red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "magenta", "cyan"})
Input colour 1: purple
Not a valid colour.
Input colour 1: cyan
Input colour 2: green
Input colour 3: yellow
Input colour 4: red
>>> colours
['cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
```